# Save a form input of an external domain iframe on a click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, iframe

On my website I'm displaying an external domain iframe.
Inside this Iframe, there is a little game. Once completed by the user, an input and an action button appear. 
I would like to get the iframe input value on the iframe click event.

**IFRAME CALL**

```
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" onload="FrameManager.registerFrame(this)" src="XXXXXX"></iframe>
```

**IFRAME DATA**

```
<input id="email" name="email">
<div id="send"></div>
```

**Questions**

1. How can I detect the click event on an external specific iframe div (#send)?
2. How can I save the input value (#email)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using $('#send').click( function() {} ); ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but as the iframe is on another domain, this can't work :/

Comment: What do you mean with another domain?

Comment: An external domain.  Ex: - url of my site: mysite.com - url of the iframe: xxxx.com

Comment: But you have the #send-div on your iframe right?

Comment: The iframe is from an external domain. These data are inside: 

<input id="email" name="email">
<div id="send"></div>

On my side, I'm calling the iframe like this: <iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" onload="FrameManager.registerFrame(this)" src="XXXXXX"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Make use of PHP (Hypertext Pre Processor) for persistent storage .
It is a sever side scripting language which will help you in accomplishing your task .

1) You said that an action button appears . Please change the following :

```
   <div id="send"></div>
```

To :

```
  <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="send"  />
```

Then all enclose your email input in a form of type POST method 
Eg :

```
       <form name="myForm" action="POST" >

              <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
              <input type="submit" value="Send" />

       </form>
```

So now , use PHP :

```
  <?php

     /* The name of the input element is "email"  */

      if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

         /*This is to check if user pressed submit button .*/

         /*Now let us take the input value in a variable called email*/

             $email = $_POST['email'];

         /*Let us save it in a file called file*/

          $file = file ;
          file_put_contents($file , $email , FILE_APPEND);

      } 

  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as it is an external iframe, I can't modify it.